# Dynamically alter graph nodes in TensorFlow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a cost function of the following form as part of the computational graph:

cost = term_1 - alpha * term_2

I want to dynamically anneal the value of alpha during training but I cannot find a straightforward way to do it. Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: is `alpha` a tensor variable?

Comment: Yes, there's a part in my code where I try to assign a new value to alpha, every 500 steps. It looks like this:

`if i % 500 == 0:
      
    st_alpha /= 2
    sess.run(alpha.assign(st_alpha))
    print("alpha:", temp)`

but I get a `RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a placeholder for the alpha. Your problem is similar to setting an adaptive learning rate, so check out this: [How to set adaptive learning rate for GradientDescentOptimizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33919948/how-to-set-adaptive-learning-rate-for-gradientdescentoptimizer)