# Tensorflow Eager Execution does not work with Learning Rate decay

Tags: tensorflow

trying here to make an eager exec model work with LR decay, but no success. It seems to be a bug, since it appear that the learning rate decay tensor does not get updated. If I am missing something can you land a hand here. Thanks.

The code bellow is learning some word embeddings. However, the **learning rate decay** section does not work at all.

```
class Word2Vec(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embed_size, num_sampled=NUM_SAMPLED):
        self.vocab_size = vocab_size
        self.num_sampled = num_sampled
        self.embed_matrix = tfe.Variable(tf.random_uniform(
            [vocab_size, embed_size]), name="embedding_matrix")
        self.nce_weight = tfe.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(
            [vocab_size, embed_size],
            stddev=1.0 / (embed_size ** 0.5)), name="weights")
        self.nce_bias = tfe.Variable(tf.zeros([vocab_size]), name="biases")

    def compute_loss(self, center_words, target_words):
        """Computes the forward pass of word2vec with the NCE loss."""
        embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.embed_matrix, center_words)
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.nce_loss(weights=self.nce_weight,
                                             biases=self.nce_bias,
                                             labels=target_words,
                                             inputs=embed,
                                             num_sampled=self.num_sampled,
                                             num_classes=self.vocab_size))
        return loss


def gen():
    yield from word2vec_utils.batch_gen(DOWNLOAD_URL, EXPECTED_BYTES,
                                        VOCAB_SIZE, BATCH_SIZE, SKIP_WINDOW,
                                        VISUAL_FLD)


def main():
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen, (tf.int32, tf.int32),
                                             (tf.TensorShape([BATCH_SIZE]),
                                              tf.TensorShape([BATCH_SIZE, 1])))

    global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
    starter_learning_rate = 1.0
    end_learning_rate = 0.01
    decay_steps = 1000
    learning_rate = tf.train.polynomial_decay(starter_learning_rate, global_step.numpy(),
                                              decay_steps, end_learning_rate,
                                              power=0.5)

    train_writer = tf.contrib.summary.create_file_writer('./checkpoints')
    train_writer.set_as_default()

    optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate, momentum=0.95)
    model = Word2Vec(vocab_size=VOCAB_SIZE, embed_size=EMBED_SIZE)
    grad_fn = tfe.implicit_value_and_gradients(model.compute_loss)
    total_loss = 0.0  # for average loss in the last SKIP_STEP steps

    checkpoint_dir = "./checkpoints/"
    checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "ckpt")
    root = tfe.Checkpoint(optimizer=optimizer,
                          model=model,
                          optimizer_step=tf.train.get_or_create_global_step())

    while global_step < NUM_TRAIN_STEPS:

        for center_words, target_words in tfe.Iterator(dataset):

            with tf.contrib.summary.record_summaries_every_n_global_steps(100):

                if global_step >= NUM_TRAIN_STEPS:
                    break

                loss_batch, grads = grad_fn(center_words, target_words)
                tf.contrib.summary.scalar('loss', loss_batch)
                tf.contrib.summary.scalar('learning_rate', learning_rate)

                # print(grads)
                # print(len(grads))
                total_loss += loss_batch
                optimizer.apply_gradients(grads, global_step)
                if (global_step.numpy() + 1) % SKIP_STEP == 0:
                    print('Average loss at step {}: {:5.1f}'.format(
                        global_step.numpy(), total_loss / SKIP_STEP))
                    total_loss = 0.0

        root.save(file_prefix=checkpoint_prefix)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 7):

Note that when eager execution is enabled, the `tf.Tensor` objects [represent concrete values](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/eager#setup_and_basic_usage) (as opposed to symbolic handles of computation that will occur on `Session.run()` calls).

As a result, in your code snippet above, the line:

```
learning_rate = tf.train.polynomial_decay(starter_learning_rate, global_step.numpy(),
                                          decay_steps, end_learning_rate,
                                          power=0.5)
```

is computing the decayed value once, using the `global_step` at the time it was invoked, and when the optimizer is being created with:

```
optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate, momentum=0.95)
```

it is being given a fixed learning rate.

To decay the learning rate, you'd want to invoke `tf.train.polynomial_decay` repeatedly (with updated values for `global_step`). One way to do this would be to replicate what is done in the [RNN example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8753e2ebde6c58b56675cc19ab7ff83072824a62/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/rnn_ptb/rnn_ptb.py#L319), using something like this:

```
starter_learning_rate = 1.0
learning_rate = tfe.Variable(starter_learning_rate)
optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate, momentum=0.95)
while global_step < NUM_TRAIN_STEPS:
   # ....
   learning_rate.assign(tf.train.polynomial_decay(starter_learning_rate, global_step, decay_steps, end_learning_rate, power=0.5))
```

This way you've captured the `learning_rate` in a variable that can be updated. Furthermore, it's simple to include the current `learning_rate` in the checkpoint as well (by including it when creating the `Checkpoint` object).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, that helped a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @ash, is there any way to accomplish this for TF Estimators where we don't directly access the training loop?

Comment: For eager mode in TF2, this solution does not work. The proper solution is to make learning rate a callable, per https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/SGD#eager_compatibility. You can confirm that the variable approach doesn't work by instantiating an optimizer with a variable learning rate, changing the value of learning rate, and calling the optimizer's get_config() method. On the other hand, the callable approach will update the optimizer's learning rate.