# Setting piece wise learning rate in TensorFlow Estimator API

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-estimator

I want to set up a piecewise learning rate for tensor-flow Estimator object, so far I am doing like this

```
boundaries = [100000, 200000, 300000]
values = [0.1, 0.05, 0.01, 0.001]
global_step = tf.train.get_global_step()
learning_rate = tf.train.piecewise_constant(global_step, boundaries, values)
```

and then creating Estimator with these model params.

It is throwing the error `ValueError: None values not supported.` since  value of global step is NONE.

On the other hand when I create `global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)`, tensor of learning rate is created but it get failed later while calling an estimator object creation.
Already cheked this one : [How to use a decaying learning rate with an estimator in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45844320/how-to-use-a-decaying-learning-rate-with-an-estimator-in-tensorflow)

Comment: This is a very valid question, why it was downvoted and flagged to be closed?. And no reasons given.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/get_or_create_global_step) instead, it will create the global step for you with its expected definition.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I tried and now it is throwing a different error while reating Estimator object.
"TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects".  Looking at the stack , it throws from init fucntion from estimator.py  while calling deep copy .  "self._params = copy.deepcopy(params or {})"