# Transfer Learning Inception V3 : Continue Training if Accuracy Fluctuating?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, training-data

I'm still doing transfer learning using Inception V3 on tensorflow. Here is the screenshot of my training using Tensorboard. 
Base training source code :  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/hub/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py

My dataset is around 1 mil with **80:10:10 training:validation:test** ratio. 
**32:128** for **training batch size:validation batch size** 
**0.001 learning rate**

[image]

As you can see the training accuracy and validation accuracy keep fluctuating (up and down). Is there any point to continue the training? Or is there something that causes this problem that I can try to solve?

Comment: Do you have more metrics? Maybe your batchsize, learning rate combination is not optimal. This often results in fluctuating. For me, more metrics are needed to give an answer

Comment: Updated my post

Comment: Have you tried reducing learning_rate?

Comment: Also try k-fold cross validation or add some regularizer.

Comment: @PallaviJog I did try 0.0005 but same result

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your accuracy is moving quite a bit.
What kind of optimizer are you using? Adam? In any case, it might help if you added in learning rate decay.

Comment: I think this is the optimizer `optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(FLAGS.learning_rate)`

Comment: check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33919948/how-to-set-adaptive-learning-rate-for-gradientdescentoptimizer

Comment: Hey thanks for suggesting `AdamOptimizer`. I tried it and works way better than `GradientDescent` (more stable and higher accuracy). Can you edit your answer little bit more like a real answer (explaining why adam is good), so I can accept your answer